# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when moving a file (only on direct children of root)

Tags: java, kotlin, file-io, nio, actor

My program is making use of the actor model to rename every folder/file in a given directory that contains a certain string (i.e.: "folder_1" -> "folder_2").

```kt
    private fun rename(msg: PathRenameMessage): Path {
        val node = msg.node
        val oldPath = node.path
        try {
            return rename(oldPath, msg.strToFind, msg.strToReplace)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw PathNotProcessedException(msg, e)
        }
    }

    private fun rename(path: Path, strToFind: String, strToReplace: String): Path {
        val newName = path.fileName.toString().replace(strToFind, strToReplace)
        val newPath = path.resolveSibling(newName)
        Files.move(path, newPath, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)
        return newPath
    }
```

At first, it starts renaming the files correctly, but when it tries to rename (using **Files.move**) the direct children of the root of the directory, it throws *java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException*.

[image: Error log]

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
The folder structure I'm currently testing this on is:
[image: Filetree]

Comment: What platform is this on? Can your user rename those files other ways (e.g. with `mv` or equivalent)?

Comment: Probably it is related to access permissions (read-only) or it is an existing directory locked by another process. Can you tell me about your OS and these directories?

Comment: My platform is Windows and I do have file access to the folders. I can rename it normally otherwise. I just edited my question with the folder structure I'm testing this on